# Display problems with button

Tags: html, css, button, filter

I have tag filter list that triggers on button click, the problem is when there is 2 or more lines of filters the active filter always pushes to the right the filter that is on the second line. If you will open fiddle, click and won't release the mouse button on  "City" for example, you will notice this unpleasant behavior.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hyg3C/4497/

**HTML**

```
  <h3>Composition</h3>
  <div class="ui-group">
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="composition">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">All</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".landscape">Landscape</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".portait">Portrait</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".square">Square</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>People</h3>
  <div class="ui-group">
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="people">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">All</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".people">People</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".nopeople">No People</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Theme</h3>
  <div class="ui-group">
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="theme">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">All</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".nature">Nature</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".fashion">City</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".mountains">Mountains</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".sea">Sea</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".sunset">Sunset</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".rain">Rain</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Place</h3>
  <div class="ui-group">
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="place">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">All</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".nature">Barcelona</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/********************************
Filter
*********************************/

ul#composition.filter, ul#people.filter, ul#theme.filter {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #434343;
}



/********************************
Sidebar
*********************************/



#sidebar-wrapper  {
    top: 0;
    background: rgb(250,250,250);
}

.start {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#sidebar.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    /*display: block;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #sidebar {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #sidebar.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #sidebar.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #sidebar.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }


@media(min-width:1366px) {
    #sidebar {
        padding-left: 24.45%;
    }

    #filter {
        max-width: 82.44%;
        margin-left: 8.78%;
    }

    #sidebar.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 24.45%
    }
}

@media(min-width:1666px) {
    #sidebar {
        padding-left: 17.88%;
    }

    div.filters {
        max-width: 82.44%;
        margin-left: 8.78%;
    }

    #sidebar.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 17.88%;
    }
}





.button {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border: none; 
  color: rgb(230,230,230);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #434343;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s;
  transition: color 1s;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #434343;
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;

}

.button.is-checked {
  color: #434343;
}

.button:active {
  color: #434343;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #434343;
}



/* ---- button-group ---- */

.button-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group .button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of JSFiddle.. next time you can use the build in system.

Comment: @Lipis JSFiddle is fine, but am I the only one who only see a blank page ?

Comment: On `:active` you've created a border that's why its causing the issue, create a transparent `border` for all `buttons` and then on `:active` just change the `transparent` color to the color you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Hyg3C/4499/)**

```
.button {
        font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 300;
        display: inline;
        background: #fff;
        border: none;
        color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px white;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
        height:22px; /* specify height 2 solve this problem */
    }
```